# Fetch new table data daily with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

The website I am working on provides a service, where only members can get full access to the content. I am trying to create a 'sample' on the homepage that fetches NEW mysql data (that is normally available for members only) every day and provides ALL users with a 'free sample' of what the site has to offer.

The database contains over one thousand entries and I would like to find a way to fetch new mysql data from the db every day.

Assuming my database looks like this:

```
id    cars
1     honda
2     volvo
3     ford
4     audi
```

I would like the 'car of the day' to be 'honda' for 24 hours, then 'ford' for 24 hours, then 'audi' for 24 hours, etc...

this is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
    //Create mysql connect variable
    $conn = mysql_connect('server', 'username', 'password');
    //kill connection if error occurs
    if(!$conn){
        die('Error: Unable to connect. <br/>' . mysql_error());
    }
    //connect to mysql database
    mysql_select_db("masdswe9", $conn);

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars");

    $name_array = Array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        $name_array[] = $row['name'];
    }
    shuffle($name_array);

   /* I would like for this to fetch NEW SQL data every 24 hours, 
   since I am shuffling names above, slot 0 will be different once I 
   come up with a way to fetch new mysql data every 24 hours */
    echo $name_array[0];
?>
```

Comment: If you're new to MySQL, **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query`. Although this is popular in examples, this function is extremely dangerous unless you're exceptionally careful. The `mysqli` series of functions and PDO are much safer. [Several examples](http://bobby-tables.com/php) demonstrate better practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a DB table called `CarOfTheDay` that you can select from (it will just have the ID of the car in the `Cars` table).  Either that or you can have a column `carOfTheDay`, or change the order of the cars, but I think those are a bit more intrusive.

Create a cron that runs once a day ans writes a random car to `CarOfTheDay`.  Then, you can do what you are doing above, but you don't have to worry about timing and you will only select one car:

```
SELECT
   cars
FROM
   CarOfTheDay
   JOIN Cars USING (id)
LIMIT 1
```

The `LIMIT` should not be necessary if you stick to one `CarOfTheDay`.

By the way, use `PDO` or `mysqli` rather than `mysql_*`.  Only select columns you need (don't use `SELECT *` in production code) .. and only select rows you need (you can randomize in the query).

Comment: I appreciate the reply, though I am really new to mySQL, your explanation goes over my head:) How would I 'time' the insertion of the ID's of the cars to the new table every 24 hours? that is the trouble I am having...

Comment: Cron job.  Just google "cron" or "crontab" and you will find a ton of inrormation (Linux only).  If you're on a windows machine you will have to use "Windows Task Scheduler" or some sort of cron emulation.  A cron job can run a program (even a PHP program if you like) that can do the DB changes you need.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying... so there is no way to accomplish this without a cron job? I am running Windows... I was hoping for a programming only solution... I was hoping to use a timestamp somehow or something similar...

Comment: @MHZ that would require knowledge of the previous state and the program would not run dependably (i.e. only every time the page was accessed).  Why would you not want to use a cron job?  They are wonderful for many tasks -- not something to be avoided.

Comment: no real reason really, I have not much experience with Linux, but I am going to give it a try, it seems like a useful thing to learn... thank you

Answer (score 2):

@Explosion Pills has a good solution for your future. In your future, some car company is going to pay you big bucks to have their product be your car of the day.

For now, let's say you just want to run through your list of cars and make each one in turn the car of the day.  Let's say your ID values are all present, with no gaps, starting at 1.

Then:

```
SELECT id, car
  FROM cars
 WHERE id >= 1+MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()),(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM cars)+1)
 ORDER BY ID
 LIMIT 1
```

will give you a new car, in id sequence, every day, from all the cars in your table.

The trick here is this expression: `1+MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()),(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM cars)+1)`

It basically does this:

1. turns today's date into a number
2. computes the maximum ID number from the table
3. takes today's date modulo that number
4. looks up the row with that id.

There's some monkey business with `1+` and `-1` because modulo arithmetic works 0 - n-1 rather than 1 - n.

Note that I used `>=` and `LIMIT 1` instead of simply `=` so your query won't collapse in a heap on a random day should you happen to end up with a gap in your id sequence.

***Edit*** This  assumes your table is called "cars" and it has columns `id` and `car`.  If that's not true you need to change the query accordingly. It's best to try to debug these things in a SQL client like phpmyadmin before programming them.   I did test this on some dummy data of my own.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb1bb/1/0

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your SELECT statement goes beyond my knowledge of mySQL, however it seems to return false, are you sure the syntax is correct?

Comment: What do you get when you do `SELECT id from cars order by id` ?

Comment: No errors, it selects all car id's and orders by id... ( I do have an id field in my db)

Comment: However, I need the SELECT statement to select a different row every 24hours.

Comment: That's what my answer gives you.

Comment: did not work for me but thanks for trying... the select statement simply returns false.